# Remote Android crash logs

Tags: android, android-debug

I know this has been asked before. I can Google.

The reason I'm raising this question again is because the last best voted answer is from like 7 years ago and I wonder if anything new/better has emerged.

So, the question is - what is the best practice to get crash logs from Android apps deployed in the field?

Comment: do u ever tried fabric????

Comment: No, I haven't. I googled a few solutions and I'm wondering what is the best/common practice today.

Comment: try fabric. Its good for app crash tracking

Comment: Fabric is one of the trending an most used platform to get alters and reports for crash log and other miscellaneous activity most of android developers in India use this only.

Comment: Hockeyapp might be an alternative too.

Comment: Use firebase with more functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fabric was acquired by google
The most powerful, yet lightest weight [crash reporting](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary) solution.

Fabric for Android Studio there is plugin in use that and it will automatically configure Crashlytics
.

Answer (score 0):

There're many websites and services targeting crash reports.

I use Fabric because it's powerful and easy to deploy. It also provides analytics.

Firebase Crash Report and Crashlytics also do the job. However, simply using their crash report is not a good choice. They need several permissions(more than Internet) and play services(probable?). Only use it when you're also using Firebase Database, Auth....

Besides, you can create your own crash report tool with a fresh start or using [libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/21?sort=rating).